# Angular 2 @Input - How to bind ID property of child component from parent component?

Tags: javascript, angular, input, typescript, output

In my parent component, I want to create a child component with a unique ID associated with it, and I want to pass that unique ID into the child component, so the child component can put that ID on its template.

Parent template:

```
<ckeditor [ckEditorInstanceID]="someUniqueID"> </ckeditor>
```

Here is the child component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'

var loadScript = require('scriptjs');
declare var CKEDITOR;

@Component({
   selector: 'ckeditor',
   template: `<div [id]="ckEditorInstanceID">This will be my editor</div>`
})
export class CKEditor {

   @Input() ckEditorInstanceID: string;

   constructor() {
      console.log(this.ckEditorInstanceID)
   }

   ngOnInit() {

   }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      loadScript('//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/standard/ckeditor.js', function() {
         CKEDITOR.replace(this.ckEditorInstanceID);
         console.info('CKEditor loaded async')
      });
   }
}
```

What am I missing? I can't seem to get the child component to receive the value of "someUniqueID". it is always undefined.

**UPDATE:** I was able to get the child component to receive the value "someUniqueID. Code udpated above. However, I cannot reference the @Input property by calling `this.ckEditorInstanceID` because `this` is undefined.

How do I reference the property I brought in via @Input?

Comment: this.ckEditorInstanceId is not going to work, you have to use an arrow function

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Iso function() {} you write () => {}

Comment: Arrow functions have block scope

Comment: If you can post a code example, that will be much appreciated. My brain is not following what to do :-/

Comment: @DavidBulté Thanks, I finally figured out what you meant by needing to use the arrow function. But I don't understand why that is, can you explain the logic?

Answer (score 1):

Don't name inputs `id`. That's conflicting with the `id` attribute of the `HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to use an arrow function like @David Bulte mentioned.

```
loadScript('//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/standard/ckeditor.js', () => {
     CKEDITOR.replace(this.ckEditorInstanceID);
     console.info('CKEditor loaded async')
  });
```

For some reason the arrow function can access `this.ckEditorInstanceID`, but a regular function() {} cannot access `this.ckEditorInstanceID`. I don't know why, maybe someone can enlighten me to the reasoning for this.

In addition, I had to change my markup like this:

```
<ckeditor [ckEditorInstanceID]="'editor1'"> </ckeditor>
<ckeditor [ckEditorInstanceID]="'editor2'"> </ckeditor>
```

And set the @Input property to the name inside the [] which is `ckEditorInstanceID` , and also the template source should be the property name `ckEditorInstanceID`, like `[id]="ckEditorInstanceID"` .

**Full working child component that receives the ID from the parent html selector:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'

var loadScript = require('scriptjs');
declare var CKEDITOR;

@Component({
   selector: 'ckeditor',
   template: `<div [id]="ckEditorInstanceID">This will be my editor</div>`
})
export class CKEditor {

   @Input() ckEditorInstanceID: string;

   constructor() {}

   ngAfterViewInit() {

      loadScript('//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/standard/ckeditor.js', () => {
         CKEDITOR.replace(this.ckEditorInstanceID);
         console.info('CKEditor loaded async')
      });
   }
}
```